# How can I replace more things with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, replace

I want to check input from users. If there's something wrong, I want that code can replace it with someting else.

This was my first try with Javascript:

```
var userInput= "Hello, I am 22 years old."
document.write(userInput.replace(/I am/g, "I'm");
```

It works fine, but I also want to replace `22` to `23`. How can I do that as simple as possible.

Comment: userInput.replace("22", "23")?

Comment: Try the same way you replace `I am` with `I'm`

Answer (score 1):

`document.write(userInput.replace(/I am/g, "I'm").replace(/22/g, "23"));`

Answer (score 0):

You may try some thing like that. Hope this helps.

```
var userInput= "Hello, I am 22 years old."
document.write(userInput.replace(/I am/g, "I'm").replace(/(\d+)/g, "23"));
```